# IntelliJ formats the whole file even if I do not highlight any code

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

My IDE is IntelliJ and my laptop is Mac OS.

When I click `Code` -> `Reformat Code`, even if I am not highlighting any code, the whole file gets reformatted.

How to make it format nothing if no code is highlighted?

Thank!

Comment: Why do you need to run this action if you don't need code formatting?

Comment: because I want to only format highlighted code.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighted code? Do you mean code selected by mouse/keyboard?

Comment: Hi yes. Selected by the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected, see corresponding [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_code):

[image]

If you don't want any of the code reformatted, do not invoke the `Reformat Code` action.

You can always undo the misfired reformatting with `Meta+Z`.